# Finite Union of Closed Sets

Tags: general-topology

Prove a finite union of closed sets is closed

Proof: Suppose $A_{\alpha_i}$, $i = 1,2,\ldots,n$ are closed and we want to prove $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_{\alpha_i}$ is closed, we know from De Morgans Law that $(\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_{\alpha_i})^c = \bigcap_{i = 1}^n A_{\alpha_i}^c$ also from the previous problem we have proved that a finite intersection of open sets is open. Therefore, $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_{\alpha_i}$ is closed.

I am not sure if am right, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. For brevity's sake just assume that I proved that a finite intersection of open sets is open.

Comment: It is standard to use "$\cap$" in things like $A\cap B$ and $A_1\cap\cdots\cap A_n$, and "$\bigcap$" in things like $\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i$. I have edited accordingly. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is quite OK. In my preferred set-up of the theory, the intersection of a finite number of open sets is open by definition of a topology. Probably you have a different approach here, but the de Morgan approach is fine regardless.